# android virtual device app has stopped

Tags: android, react-native

Logcat:

```
12-02 11:14:33.964 28382-28382/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni     (already on)
12-02 11:14:33.964 28382-28382/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using    defaults: x86
12-02 11:14:34.048 28382-28382/com.reactnativewebhelloworld    
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM --------- beginning of crash
12-02 11:14:34.049 28382-28382/com.reactnativewebhelloworld E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.reactnativewebhelloworld, PID: 28382
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.reactnativewebhelloworld/com.reactnativewebhelloworld.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
      at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.getReactNativeHost(ReactActivityDelegate.java:72)
      at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:80)
      at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:54)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Надо добавить в манифест

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вы обнаружили ошибку? Мне это очень интересно, т.к. я не умею этот лог.

Comment: @Vaom У вас в логе `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication`, это популярная проблема, например после обновления react native и ответ гуглится по этой строчке. Я просто нашел ключевую строку в логе.

Comment: Теперь такая ошибка java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to instantiate application ... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.reactnativewebhelloworld.ReactNativeWebHelloWorld" on path: DexPathList [[zip file "/data/app/com.reactnativewebhelloworld-2/base.apk"]]

Comment: @Vaom мало инфы. Похоже что вы используете часть кода [отсюда](https://github.com/kauffecup/react-native-web-hello-world), но там нет класса ReactNativeWebHelloWorld.

Comment: Может [полный logcat](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598734/android-virtual-device-app-has-stopped-js-react-java-lang-classnotfoundexcepti) поможет

Comment: Так почему у вас `ReactNativeWebHelloWorld`, а не MainApplication в манифесте?

Comment: Просто это не чего не меняет, по этому я поставил ReactNativeWebHelloWorld, но исправил на MainApplication. Но ошибка та же осталась

Comment: @Vaom Ты ведь используешь Android Studio? Посмотри какие классы наследуются от ReactApplication. Если никакие не наследуются, то создай свой класс-наследник ReactApplication и указывай его в манифесте. Если какие-то наследуются, то надо разбираться.

Comment: Наследуется MainApplication "public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication"

Comment: Тогда надо package этого MainApplication подставить. `android:name="<some_package>.MainApplication"`
И скорее всего для MainActivity тоже он понадобится.

Comment: Результат тот же

Comment: @Vaom Покажи манифест полностью

Comment: Манифест полностью [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598734/android-virtual-device-app-has-stopped-js-react-java-lang-classnotfoundexcepti)

Comment: Не вижу чтобы в манифесте был представлен package. А что в build.gradle? Надо понять как там импортируется библиотека.

Comment: @Vaom Я имел в виду что не подставлен package для MainApplication.